# JPA ManyToOne With repeated entries

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, many-to-one

I have a spring boot application. The endpoint directly maps a json post body to my entities.
For simplicity sake lets just use two:

```
@Entity
public class Metric {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

   private int value;

   @ManyToOne
   private Labels labels;

   ...
}


@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "label", "source" }) })
public class Labels {

    @Id 
    private int id;

    private string label;
    private string source;
    ...
}
```

Spring Rest's `@Requestbody` directly deserializes to `Metric`. Since unlike this example my actual Entity is deeply nested I figured I could just `CASCADE.ALL` on the `@ManyToOne`. This works, until Labels repeats itself. This throws an exception because of the UniqueConstraint.

So I tried to create a Static factory method for Labels and use @JsonCreator. Then use the JpaRepository to check if the Entity already exists. Unfortunately JpaRepository cannot be used in static context.

I feel this should be easily achievable but somehow can't manage to get it working. Is this just a limit of JPA or am I missing something?

I'd be grateful for a push in the right direction.

Comment: I'm guessing your incoming data didn't maintain the id int values. If label and source uniquely identify your Labels row data, you need to use that as the ID for JPA to be able to find it for you on a merge/save call and know that it already exists. Or, you need to look up each incoming label based on that label, source combination and use that reference instead of saving it again as a new entity.